# science fiction story about scientists who create a personal force field which makes a halo appear around their heads when it is on

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a story that I read as a child. The synopsis is something like:

"a science fiction story about scientists who create a personal force field which makes a halo appear around their heads when it is on and they use this like gods or angels to trick a foreign invading military to back down"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  We don't know when you were a child, so what year would you have read this?  Was it a book or a short story?

Comment: The accepted answer is not what I expected.  I have a vague memory of a short SciFi story where someone rigged a forcefield to protect from alien natives - found they went from hostile to friendly.  Eventually went out without the forcefield & was killed because they "didn't have the halo"  Don't have enough details at the moment to make a separate question but I might if I can remember more.

Comment: It's not considered good practice to edit your question to include the answers and/or "thank you" statements - it should stand on its own. In fact, at least on Stack Overflow (the main Stack Exchange programming site), even **comments** that say only  "thank you" (and don't include other information) are deprecated - upvoting and accepting answers are supposed to be sufficient.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like Robert Heinlein's novel, "The Day after Tomorrow".

Comment: You should explain what parts of the novel match, at least name the characters and describe the scene when this happens.

Comment: While the novel is obvious note that the halo is not a required part of the force field, it was done for show.

Answer (score 15):

AKA Sixth Column. The USA is invaded by the "Pan-Asians" and all American citizens are enslaved. Anyone who is part Japanese is killed. The last few scientists in an underground fortress have discovered new scientific principles; and can transmute matter and use a new undetectable communications system. They set up a new religion as a cover for their activities and recruit Americans into it and pose as priests; which is where the halo effect comes into play.

Comment: Not really a different answer.  Should probably be a comment.

Comment: But, very useful information!